# Redis FTAggregate with SORT BY doesnt work with Cursor

Tags: java, redis

I am trying to process some data in batches using FTAggregate in Java. If I use sortBy I get results only on the ft.aggregate call and no results on subsequent cursor reads. My sort field is indexed as NUMERIC and SORTABLE. Am I doing something wrong or is it desired behaviour? Because I couldn't find any info on CURSOR and SORT BY interaction on Redis doc. Everything works fine if i remove the sortBy(). If I let only the sortBy() without limit() I get only 10 results and no subsequent ones because default limit for sort by is 10 if not specified otherwise. So my question is, can sortBy can work with CURSOR or should I use LIMIT with offset for paginating even if it would mean nuking the performance?

```
public void fetchData() {
   var chuckSize = 1000;
   var result = jedis.ftAggregate("myIndex", new AggregationBuilder("*")
                     .loadAll()
                     .sortBy("myField")
                     .limit(chuckSize)
                     .cursor(chuckSize, 1000));
   var cursor = new AtomicLong(result.getCursorId());
   while(true) {
       try {
         //process result
         result = jedis.ftCursorRead("myIndex",cursor.get(), chunckSize);
         cursor.set(result.getCursorId());
       } catch(JedisDataException e) {
         //data read end
         break;
       }
}
```

Comment: I’m not too familiar with Jedis, but I know for sure that it is possible to use cursors and sorter together, and it should work as expected (sort by something, limit 0 100, cursor count 10 will give you 10 results at first, and then 10 on every read until you got all 100)

Comment: 1) How many total results do you have for the ft.aggregate query? 2) How you certain that everything is working fine if you just remove the sortby?

Answer (score 0):

It seem to me that you simply deplete your query on the first iteration.

Try giving a smaller read count to the cursor. The default sort limit is 10 and can be larger, but it represents the **total number of results** your query will yield.

The cursor should get the number of results to give on every read, and if you give it the number of results you limited the query to, you will get them all on the first call.

From Jedis code:

```java
  public AggregationBuilder cursor(int count) {
    isWithCursor = true;
    aggrArgs.add(SearchKeyword.WITHCURSOR);
    aggrArgs.add(SearchKeyword.COUNT);
    aggrArgs.add(count);
    return this;
  }

  public AggregationBuilder cursor(int count, long maxIdle) {
    isWithCursor = true;
    aggrArgs.add(SearchKeyword.WITHCURSOR);
    aggrArgs.add(SearchKeyword.COUNT);
    aggrArgs.add(count);
    aggrArgs.add(SearchKeyword.MAXIDLE);
    aggrArgs.add(maxIdle);
    return this;
  }
```

Seems like a cursor gets either the chunk size, or the chunk size and an expatriation limit (like other keys in redis).

You need to define your query limit.
Try something like this:

```
public void fetchData() {
   var chuckSize = 1000;
   var queryLimit = chunkSize * 10;
   var result = jedis.ftAggregate("myIndex", new AggregationBuilder("*")
                     .loadAll()
                     .sortBy("myField")
                     .limit(queryLimit)
                     .cursor(chuckSize));
   var cursor = new AtomicLong(result.getCursorId());
   while(true) {
       try {
         //process result
         result = jedis.ftCursorRead("myIndex",cursor.get(), chunckSize);
         cursor.set(result.getCursorId());
       } catch(JedisDataException e) {
         //data read end
         break;
       }
}
```